# Im unable to send appropriate error message to the client when using multer(upload.any() )

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, async-await, multer

I'm using this middleware to upload files into an AWS S3 bucket. However, there has been a problem: I'm unable to enter Multer's error block while filtering the type of files in fileFilter.

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const crypto = require('crypto');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const { AwsUploadFile } = require('../../utils/s3');

const generateFileName = (mimeType, bytes = 32) => {
  const extension = mimeType.split('/')[1]; // Extracts file extension from MIME type
  return crypto.randomBytes(bytes).toString('hex') + '.' + extension;
};

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype.startsWith('image/') ||
    file.mimetype.startsWith('video/')
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }, // 50MB limit
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});

async function fileUpload(req, res, next) {
  const multerUpload = upload.any();
  multerUpload(req, res, async (err) => {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error uploading file',
        error: err.message,
      });
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
      console.log('General error:', err.message);

      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'An error occurred while processing',
        error: err.message,
      });
    }

    if (!req.files || req.files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'No files uploaded',
      });
    }

    const file = req.files[0];
    const getFileName = generateFileName(file.mimetype);
    file.originalname = file.mimetype.startsWith('video/')
      ? 'public/videos/' + getFileName
      : 'public/images/' + getFileName;

    if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image/')) {
      try {
        const fileBuffer = await sharp(file.buffer)
          .resize({ height: 1920, width: 1080, fit: 'contain' })
          .toBuffer();

        file.buffer = fileBuffer;
      } catch (sharpError) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Error processing image',
          error: sharpError.message,
        });
      }
    }

    try {
      const { fileLink, result } = await AwsUploadFile({
        fileBuffer: file.buffer,
        fileName: file.originalname,
        mimeType: file.mimetype,
      });

      req.fileUrl = fileLink;
      req.fileType = file.mimetype.split('/')[0];
      next();
    } catch (awsError) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error uploading to AWS',
        error: awsError.message,
      });
    }
  });
}

module.exports = fileUpload;
```

If I throw an error, then I am able to get into it, but I'm unable to send these headers:
`return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'An error occurred while processing', error: err.message })`
when i use cb(null, false) in  fileFilter func, Multer skips the file without triggering an error but i want to throw an error if its not a valid file type and  i need to send that   invalid file type error  to the  client

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fileFilter function in Multer is designed to simply filter out files based on certain criteria, and it does not directly propagate an error to the error handler. If you want to handle the invalid file type as an error and return a response to the client, you can try throwing an error in the fileFilter function when an invalid file type is encountered. Multer should catch this error, and you can handle it in the error block of your middleware. Try something like this,

```js
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image/') || file.mimetype.startsWith('video/')) {
    cb(null, true)
  } else {
    cb(new Error('Invalid file type'))
  }
}
```